# How can create HQL Query like Laravel?

Tags: java, hibernate, laravel, hql

My laravel eloquent is the following:

```
Module::select(['a', 'b'])
                ->whereRaw("OR a ='one' OR a = 'five' OR a ='ten'")
                ->distinct()
                ->orderBy('a', 'ASC')
                ->get();
```

How can I convert it into hibernate?

Comment: Can you tell which is the table name? i'm not familiar with `Laravel` but `HQL` i do.?

Comment: `select distinct a from table where a in ('one',five','ten')` is this you want?

Comment: read [this](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html)

Comment: Table Name id Module

Comment: vipin cp sir you use distinct only a but i can multiple that is a and b

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `toSql()` method to get the SQL query.

For example

```
DB::table('users')->toSql();
```

returns the query

```
select * from users
```

Then you have to translate the SQL to HQL, using some [manual](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html).

Answer (score 0):

[Spring Data](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-creation) allows you to create queries using the method name.

Example:

```
 List<Module> findDistinctModuleByAOrderByAAsc(String a);
```